# How to make a new column based on condition from multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe contains a few columns where the value is either 0 or 1

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

So how to create a new column "F" where the condition is :

- if column A,B,C,D,E contains 1 so the value of F will be 1.

Here's an example of the expected output

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I tried using

```
def stress(df1):
    if 0 not in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    
df1['F'] = df1.apply (stress, axis=1)
df1
```

but the output became like this

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

followed by this warning message :

```
c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3607: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._set_item(key, value)
```

Comment: Why do you expect `if 0 not in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')` to ever be false? 0 is not equal to any of those strings

Answer (score 2):

```
df['F'] = df.max(axis=1)
```

or

```
df['F'] = df.any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0  0  1
2  0  0  1  1  0  1
3  0  0  0  0  1  1
```